# Adding a dropdown box in Datagridview

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Datagridview which is showing some records from DB. Now I want to add a dropdown menu in between the columns of this Datagridview.

How could I achieve that? My DGrid is bound in runtime so I am not initializing every column here!

Help?

Answer (score 5):

Use below code to add your Combobox Column at specific index of DataGridView

```
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn myCombo=new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        myCombo.HeaderText = "My Combo";
        myCombo.Name = "myCombo";
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(n, myCombo); // n is index
```